# jQuery plugin vertical scroll fullheight page

Tags: jquery, plugins

Someone know the name of plugin or the way to perform a vertical page per page like the one in this site?
http://karimrashid.com/overview#about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These application are single page applications:
Try this plugin:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, and installed the same plugin! btw you deserve the best answer